# "Location is not set" JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Tenho estudado javafx recentemente e fiquei travado ao escrever um código bem simples para abrir um arquivo .fxml, segue o código e o erro respectivamente, procurei pela internet e já tentei a solução proposta no stackoverflow americano, e mesmo assim o problema persiste, alguém sabe como conserto isso? Obrigado!

Obs. Perdoem a minha formatação, é minha primeira vez postando aqui.

---

```
package projeto;


public class MainApp extends Application {
    private Stage primaryStage;
    private static BorderPane rootLayout;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("CineTudo");

    initRootLayout();

    showFilmeOverview();
}

public void initRootLayout(){
    try {
        //Carrega o layout root do arquivo fxml
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(MainApp.class.getResource("/fxml/RootLayout.fxml"));
        rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

        Scene cena = new Scene(rootLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(cena);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    }
    public static void showFilmeOverview() {

    try {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(MainApp.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/fxml/FilmeOverview.fxml"));
        AnchorPane filmeOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        rootLayout.setCenter(filmeOverview);
    }catch (IOException e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
    public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }
}
```

---

> Exception in Application start method
>     java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
>       at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2434)
>       at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
>       at projeto.MainApp.initRootLayout(MainApp.java:34)
>       at projeto.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:25)
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
>       ... 1 more
>   Exception running application projeto.MainApp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para carregar um .fxml certifique-se de informar o caminho deste arquivo relativo à pasta `src` do projeto. O exemplo abaixo considera que dentro da pasta `src` possui as seguintes subpastas que contém o arquivo .fxml: `br/com/view`.

```
public class MainApp extends Application {
    ...
    public void initRootLayout(){
        try {
            String caminhoPagina = "/br/com/view/FilmeOverview.fxml";
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(caminhoPagina));
            ...
        }
        ...
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.